# AssertionError when I try to write a unit test

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I'm creating the processor to collect data and provide them in list. But when I'm trying to create test for my method i'm catching assertionerror. What am I doing wrong?

**My Class:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ZteProcessor implements OurProcessor {

    private final static String VENDOR = "ZTE";

    private String jsonString;
    private Map<String, String> metricsGU;
    private Map<String, String> metricsUMTS;
    private Map<String, String> metricsLTE;

    @Override
    public List<TimingAdvance> getTA() throws ParseException, NotFoundPatternOrMetricsException {
        TimeAdvanceDataStore data = new TimeAdvanceDataStore();
        AllDataFromJSONFile fromJSONFile = ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString);
        if (jsonString.contains("String")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, fromJSONFile, metricsGU, 2);
        } else if (jsonString.contains("String-2")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, fromJSONFile, metricsUMTS, 3);
        } else if (jsonString.contains("String3")) {
            return data.allDataToTimingAdvance(VENDOR, fromJSONFile, metricsLTE, 4);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundPatternOrMetricsException();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Test:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProcessorUtil.class})
public class ZteProcessorTest {

    @Mock
    private AllDataFromJSONFile fromJSONFile;
    @Mock
    private TimeAdvanceDataStore data;

    private OurProcessor processor;

    private TimingAdvance timingAdvance = new TimingAdvance();

    private Map<String, String> metricsGU = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> metricsUMTS = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, String> metricsLTE = new HashMap<>();

    @Test
    public void getTATest() throws Exception {
        String jsonString = " { String : value}";
        processor = new ZteProcessor(jsonString, metricsGU, metricsUMTS, metricsLTE);
        List<TimingAdvance> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(timingAdvance);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProcessorUtil.class);

        when(ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString)).thenReturn(fromJSONFile);
        when(data.allDataToTimingAdvance(jsonString, fromJSONFile, metricsGU, 2)).thenReturn(list);
        assertEquals(list, processor.getTA());
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[TimingAdvance{filial='null', vendor='null', cellName='null', periodDate=null, taMetrics=null}]
Actual   :[]
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
```

My ZteProcessor using static method `getAllData(jsonString)` of class `ProcessorUtill`. And for it I use powermock.

Comment: your AllDataFromJSONFile is a local variable in the method, you can't mock it like that. Make it a class-level variable.

Comment: @Stultuske I tried to do this, but the result is the same. Why am I getting an empty list even though I'm stabbingthis behavior?

Comment: I don't see a Mock for your ProcessorUtil

Comment: @Stultuske ProcessorUtil is a class with static methods, and I mock of them with `PowerMockito.mockStatic (ProcessorUtil.class)` and then: `when(ProcessorUtil.getAllData(jsonString)).thenReturn(fromJSONFile)`

Comment: have you debugged your class to see where it all goes wrong?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, it goes into the `(data.allDataToTimingAdvance(jsonString, fromJSONFile, metricsGU, 2)` method and cannot collect data there. But I don’t understand why he enters to it, if I stubing him

Comment: as your code is, I don't see how you can mock it, since it's strictly a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are setting your expectations on a `TimeAdvanceDataStore data` mock, but you are creating a new instance of `TimeAdvanceDataStore` in your method under test.

Since you are already using PowerMockito, you can tap into new object creation like

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(TimeAdvanceDataStore.class)
            .withAnyArguments().thenReturn(data);
```

On top of that, think how many ZTEProcessors and TimeAdvanceDataStores you have in your app. Do you always want a new instance of TimeAdvanceDataStore in each call to getTA?

If not, just pass TimeAdvanceDataStore in a constructor.

If yes, common approaches when PowerMockito is not at your disposal are:

- passing a factory of TimeAdvanceDataStore to ZTEProcessor constructor
- passing TimeAdvanceDataStore to getTA method
- extracting a method constructing TimeAdvanceDataStore and overriding it in test